# Can Magento 2 Admin Panel bundle js files?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, bundle

I want a faster Admin Panel and I'm wondering if it's possible to bundle the js files, just like the Magepack module, but in the Admin Panel.
I'm researching in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html but, I'm not still sure if this technique can achieve it in the Admin Panel.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Default Magento JS Bundling work for frontend only.
So, **No** its not work for admin